# Getx doesn't update my list on the screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm building a simple note-taking app, all the notes are being fetched from the backend 'localhost'. when I first log in and navigate to the `notes_screen.dart` the app doesn't show the notes, even though they have been fetched and are being added to the list! but the stranger thing is when I hot reload the app the list does appear!!
here is my `NotesScreen`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_lorem/flutter_lorem.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/controllers/login_controller.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/controllers/notes_controller.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/screens/empty_state_screen.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/screens/notes/note_viewer_screen.dart';

import '../../widgets/note_card.dart';
import 'new_note.dart';

class NotesPage extends GetWidget<NotesController> {
  final log = Logger("NotesPage");

  NotesPage({super.key});

  LoginController loginController = Get.find<LoginController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     // some code 
      body: Obx(
        () => controller.isNotesListEmpty()
            ? const Center(child: EmptyState())
            : Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: controller.notesList.value.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Dismissible(
                        key: UniqueKey(),
                        secondaryBackground: Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                          ),
                        ),
                        background: Container(color: Colors.red),
                        onDismissed: (direction) {
                          controller
                              .deleteNote(controller.notesList.value[index].id);
                        },
                        child: NoteCard(
                          note: controller.notesList.value[index],
                          onTap: () async {
                            Get.to(() => NoteViewer(),
                                arguments: controller.notesList.value[index]);
                          },
                          onLongPress: () async {
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) {
                                return AlertDialog(
                                  title: Text('delete_msg'.tr),
                                  actions: [
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        controller.deleteNote(controller
                                            .notesList.value[index].id);
                                      },
                                      child: Text('yes'.tr),
                                    ),
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Get.back();
                                      },
                                      child: Text('no'.tr),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
      ),
    // some code
    );
  }
}
```

My `NotesController`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/models/new_note_model.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/models/note_model.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/screens/notes/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/services/rest_apis.dart';

class NotesController extends GetxController {
  final log = Logger("NotesController");
  Rx<List<Note>> notesList = Rx<List<Note>>([]);
  var titleController = TextEditingController();
  var contentController = TextEditingController();
  RestAPIs restAPI = Get.find<RestAPIs>();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getAllNotes();
    ever(notesList, (callback) => null);
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    log.fine("The controller has been deleted");
  }

  bool isNotesListEmpty() {
    if (notesList.value.isEmpty) {
      log.warning("The list notes is Empty!");
      return true;
    } else {
      log.fine("The list notes is not Empty!");
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future getAllNotes() async {
    var results = await restAPI.fetchAllNotes();
    List<Note> notes = List.generate(
      results.length,
      (index) => Note.fromJson(results[index]),
    );
    log.info("The length of the notesList ${notes.length.toString()}");
    notesList.value.addAll(notes);
  }
```

here is my log when I run the app

```
[GETX] Instance "NotesController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "NotesController" has been initialized
I/flutter ( 4179): WARNING: 2023-10-15 04:58:45.435093: The list notes is Empty!
I/flutter ( 4179): INFO: 2023-10-15 04:58:45.577467: The length of the notesList 10
```

as you can see after the 'NotesController' is created and initializing the data is saved on the list, note that the log shows that the list is empty because the response hasn't come through yet, after that the data arrived, but the screen doesn't update

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this problem and I solved it by the following :

in the `NotesController`

```
Future<List<Note>> getAllNotes() async {
    var results = await restAPI.fetchAllNotes();`enter code here`
    List<Note> notes = List.generate(
      results.length,
      (index) => Note.fromJson(results[index]),
    );
    log.info("The length of the notesList ${notes.length.toString()}");
    notesList.value.addAll(notes);
    return notes; // <-- 
  }
```

in the `NotesScreen` :

```
          .
          .
          .
          body: FutureBuilder<List<Note>>(
          future: controller.getAllNotes(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<List<Note>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List<Note> notes= snapshot.data; // use notes instead of controller.notesList.value now
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: notes.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Dismissible(
                        key: UniqueKey(),
                        secondaryBackground: Container(
                         .
                         .
                         .
                      );
                    }),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              // error widget
            } else {
              return const Center(child: EmptyState());
            }
          }),
          .
          .
          .
```

I know there is other solutions but this looks good to me. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could call just `.addAll()` not `.value.addAll()`.

Because `.value.addAll()` is for only adding,

but `.addAll()` of **RxList** is for adding and refreshing.

```dart
Future getAllNotes() async {
  ...
  // notesList.value.addAll(notes);
  notesList.addAll(notes);
}
```

Comment: It's an RX, I need to call value first in order to reach the list's properties.

Comment: RxList also has `addAll` method. You don't need to use value when adding elements.